# script to cd into many directories and execute a command

Tags: scripting, zsh

I'm trying to write a script that I can add to later on.  Basically, I have a collection of git repos all over my home directory.  I'd like to keep a master list of their locations and then have a script run through them all and run a `git up` command or `git pull` or something.

I'm tired of having to `cd` into everything individually to get it to update.  I'd like to do it all at once, but there's no rhyme or reason to their locations, and I'd prefer not to restructure my home folder tree just to accommodate some scripting action.

I'm more than happy to have this like a config file where I can simply append more directories to the beginning of the file as needed over time.

**EDIT:**

Here's where I'm at:

```
CWD="$(pwd)";
cd ;
dir1="$HOME/FW/foo";
dir2="$HOME/FW/bar";


for repo in $dir1, $dir2;
do 
  cd "$repo"
  git up  
done
cd $CWD
```

Oh, and I'm using ZSH, not bash...

Comment: Note that there are already existing solutions to this, like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/checkoutmanager and http://myrepos.branchable.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# This will attempt to do a `git pull` in any directories found in the
# present working directory.

for d in *; do
    if [[ -d "$d"/.git ]]; then
        ( cd $d; git pull )
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why not just `for d in */; do [[ -d "$d/.git" ]] && ( cd $d && git pull); done`?

Comment: add a `cd -` after the `git pull` ?

Comment: "...there's no rhyme or reason to their locations..." ;) I suspect looking at `git`'s `--git-dir` or `-C` options would be useful.

Comment: That's a good point.  I have things from github that I'm just interested in for a little bit, projects that have hung around for a long time, things i've forgotten about and things i'm actively working on.  This is pretty good!  I will add some echo's to point out what repos it's finding...part of my issue here is remembering what i've got on here, as well.

Comment: @mazs no need, that's why DopeGhoti is using the `(subshell)`.

Comment: This looks like it only looks down one layer, though, right?  Can it traverse the whole tree?  So, I've got some git folders that are a few layers down from the $HOME directory...How can I reach those guys if I call this in $HOME?

Comment: `for d in $(find $HOME/ -type d -name .git); do ( cd "$d"/..; git pull ); done`.

Comment: Pleased to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually have to change directory into a git repository in order to run a command with `git`. You can pass the working directory to `git` with `-C path`.

If you want to keep a list of repositories, I would suggest using an array:

```sh
repos=(
$HOME/somedir/repo1
"$HOME/somedir/with space/repo2"
)

for repo in $repos; do
    git -C $repo $@
done
```

If you put this in a script, say with tha name `multigit`, you can run any `git` command on it, as the arguments are passad withing `$@`. For example `multigit pull`.

If you do not care about configuring a list of repositories, you can even get `zsh` to find them all for you:

```sh
for repo in **/.git(/N); do
    git -C ${repo:h} $@
done
```

`**/.git(/N)` will recursively search for any directory named `.git` and `${repo:h}` will remove the last element of a path, in this case `.git`, leaving you with the paths to the repositories.

---

Bonus: you can even get <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion for your new command:

```sh
compdef '_dispatch git git' multigit
```

Comment: Whoa that's sweet!